# cannot run compiled c++ executable on OSX, works on Debian

Tags: c++, macos, g++, debian

i have a c++ program contained in a single file, `movie2serial.cpp`. i am compiling the program using g++ with the following command:

`g++ -std=c++0x -lstdc++ -lpthread -lboost_system movie2serial.cpp -o movie2serial`

this produces an executable called `movie2serial`. on Debian Wheezy (running on a Raspberry Pi) i have no trouble running this executable. however, i just tried to compile the same program on OSX, using the same call to g++. i tried `./movie2serial` and `open ./movie2serial` from the appropriate directory but these commands just return the following error:

`open: No such file or directory`

when i run `file ./movie2serial` it returns this:

`./movie2serial: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

why can't i execute my program?

Comment: What does `ls -al` give you for that file?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 <username>  staff  239828 15 Dec 20:20 movie2serial`

Comment: i tried `chmod +x ./movie2serial` as well, which didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your compilation failed.

Try executing the command below and check whether you have a file named movie2serial.

```
ls -al
```

When I try to compile using the command line options that you have given, it gives me the following error with -lboost_system.

```
ld: library not found for -lboost_system
```

Comment: look at the comments on my original post - `ls -al` gives the expected result. you probably get an error with `-lboost_system` because you don't have the boost libraries?

Comment: Which is the OS version and hardware (Intel/PowerPC) being used?